# Is posible to change TimeZone of Room db in Android?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, mobile, android-room

I currently have the following query in a Room database:

```
@Query("select * from items WHERE DATE(timestamp, 'unixepoch')=:date ORDER BY timestamp ASC")
fun getItemsByDate(date: String): LiveData<List<Item>>
```

But is getting the same result when trying to test different time zones. I checked out the current time in my Room DB and `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` gives me *UTC* time.

Is there a way to match the time zone in Room database with the device time zone?

Comment: I think I'll end up using only timestamps in Kotlin, not in Room DB:

`select * from items WHERE timestamp >= :minTimestamp and timestamp < :maxTimestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC`

`minTimestamp` will be today at *00:00+timezone*, and `maxTimestamp` will be today at *23:59+timezone*